# Beamer multi-page notes and duplicated slides

Tags: beamer, notes

I am trying to generate two versions of my slides: one with the notes on the side, and one without any notes for sharing/distribution purposes. Some of my presentation slides have several note-pages. The problem is that when I hide the notes using `\setbeameroption{hide notes}`, I get a pdf that repeats the parent slide several times (equal to the number of note-pages I had originally).

My question is: is it possible to generate a pdf without note and no duplicated presentation slides?

Here is a MWE that replicates what I mentioned:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{hide notes} % Both
%\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
% Repeat slide title
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \pagecolor{yellow!15}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
        {\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par}
        \insertnote
    \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Slide with several note pages is duplicated}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item There are too many things to say in this slide
        \item That is why I need several pages for notes
    \end{itemize}
    % Notes
    \note<1>{Hello from note 1}
    \note<2>{Hello from note 2}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the answer to this is very simple. Just add the option `handout` to the beamer class and that would remove duplicated slides, which ultimately, are created as overlays. This is,

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
```